# Strange compiler errors with code::blocks

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I switched from Visual Studio to Code::Blocks yesterday, and just had some strange compiler error messages.

I included windows.h and i can use all the API calls just fine, such as creating window classes and creating windows / buttons and stuff. But when I tried to send some keypresses with `SendInput()`, I got error messages on these two declarations:

```
INPUT ip;
KEYBDINPUT kbi;
```

Compiler errors:

```
C:\code_blocks\test-app\main.cpp|21|error: 'INPUT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\code_blocks\test-app\main.cpp|22|error: 'KEYBDINPUT' was not declared in this scope|
```

I can even right click the `KEYBDINPUT` and `INPUT` structors and click on "Find declaration", it finds it inside the "winuser.h" (which is inside ), but it's still giving me these error messages that they are not declared.

This code works fine in VS with just windows.h included. I'm using the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: Are you sure your class or CPP file has properly included that header? Otherwise it has no idea what the symbols INPUT and KEYBDINPUT mean.

Comment: yes, because i can use other functions and declarations from the windows.h / winuser.h, but these two structors which are in winuser.h say they are not declared, but they are! i can see them inside the winuser.h :/

Comment: "I switched from Visual Studio to Code::Blocks" - why would you do such a thing? :P

Comment: because its slow and bloated, and if i compile a c++ win32 application with vs, and then try to run it on another freshly installed win7 computer, it gives gives stupid errors until i install the SDK,

Comment: @kaijethegreat: you say it is slow, but how much time have you spent fixing the problems that the move caused?  Moreover Code::Blocks is an IDE not a compiler, so is perhaps unfairly blamed here; what compiler are you using with it?  With respect to deploying VC++ applications, you need to either statically link the library code or deploy the redistributable package with your application - you do not need the whole SDK!

Comment: using the GNU GCC one, anyway I tried all these things, still can't use anything in winuser.h,
i even did #include <winuser.h> and it lets me right click and go to definition, it finds it and the program even suggests keywords from winuser.h when im typing, but when i compile it says their not declared. :/ back to visual studio i suppose

Comment: @kaijthegreat: What version of VS are you running? 2005? The VS 2005 SP1 Redistributable package is pretty easy to find on Microsoft's website. You also need the .NET Runtime redistributable for the version of .NET you are compiling against also.

Comment: well
#define WINVER 0x0400
found in windef.h, which is inside windows.h
and then
#define _WIN32_WINNT WINVER

I noticed i can't use anything at all in winuser.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the pre-processor directives (Visual Studio may already add them):

What do you have `_WIN32_WINNT` defined as?

Perhaps you could add:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#endif
```

or you can add it to your pre-processor directives as part of your compile sequence. Any good compiler will have it.

If it still doesn't work, remove the include guards and define it directly. Maybe it is getting defined elsewhere.

Some compilers will have this in the pre-processor directive settings: `WIN32,_DEBUG,_CONSOLE,_MBCS,_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400`

Comment: well #define WINVER 0x0400 found in windef.h, which is inside windows.h and then #define _WIN32_WINNT WINVER I noticed i can't use anything at all in winuser.h

Comment: Finally, you got me on the right track, i defined WINVER as 0x0400, but it still didn't work, but then tried 0x0500, and it worked... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Changeling's answer, if you look at the documentation for say [KEYBDINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271%28VS.85%29.aspx), you will see that near the bottom it has a table of minimal supported OS versions.  VC++ sets _WIN32_WINNT to a later version than MinGW/GCC  (which I am guessing is the compiler you are using with Code::Blocks), which is probably why you have encountered this problem.

The purpose of this macro is to prevent you inadvertently using API's that are not compatible with your minimum intended target OS.

There are a number of version related macros used by Windows API headers.  The details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx)