# 'INPUT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to compile a program I wrote a few years ago that simulates mouse clicks and key strokes. I've reduced it to this minimal example:

```
#include "Windows.h"

int main(){
    INPUT foo;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
C:\projects\clicker>g++ minimaltest.cpp
minimaltest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
minimaltest.cpp:4:2: error: 'INPUT' was not declared in this scope
minimaltest.cpp:4:8: error: expected ';' before 'foo'
```

MSDN's page on [INPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says it's defined in Windows.h, so I don't know why it doesn't recognize the type.

Another stackoverflow user had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268252/strange-compiler-errors-with-codeblocks), but their solution, adding `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500`, didn't fix the errors.

I was able to build the program years ago on windows XP. Could it be that INPUT doesn't work on Windows 7 the way it did on XP? Or maybe I forgot to supply a flag to the compiler?

Comment: Where in your code did you add the define? It should be the first line in what you have.

Comment: @chris, good detective work. I put the define after `include` and before `main`. It didn't occur to me to put it before the `include`, although in hindsight it's obvious. It's working now.

Comment: Oh, kind of surprised that's all, but...

Comment: Well, in a buggy five line program, the solution is bound to be something minute and silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misplaced your `#define` to after the `#include`. The result of this is that `windows.h` sees `_WIN32_WINNT` as undefined, so `INPUT` is not declared. Then you define it after `INPUT`'s chance of existing has passed.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 //RIGHT
#include "Windows.h"
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 //WRONG

int main(){
    INPUT foo;
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note, unless `windows.h` is in the same directory as the source file, it should typically be imported using `#include <>` rather than `#include ""`.

Comment: defining _WIN32_WINNT  _ >=_  **0x0403** would be suffice.