# unknown type INPUT - windows.h

Tags: c, windows, input

I've been experimenting with the windows.h library recently, and the compiler is not able to find some of the types and functions that I use.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void moveUp(int with) {
    POINT pos;
    if (!GetCursorPos(&pos)) {
        puts("Unable to get cursor position\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (!SetCursorPos(pos.x, pos.y - with)) {
        puts("Unable to move cursor\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    puts("Success");
}

int getScreenHeight() {
    return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
}

void click(int x, int y) {
    INPUT myInput;
    myInput.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    MOUSEINPUT mouseStruct;
    mouseStruct.dx = x;
    mouseStruct.dy = y;
    mouseStruct.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN;
    mouseStruct.mouseData = XBUTTON1;
    mouseStruct.time = 0;
    mouseStruct.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    myInput.mi = mouseStruct;
    SendInput(1,&myInput,sizeof(INPUT));
}

void startMenu() {
    int height = getScreenHeight();
    if(!SetCursorPos(20,height + 20)){
        puts("Unable to move cursor\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    click();
}

int main(){
   moveUp(200);
   startMenu();
   return 0;
 }
```

And I get the error above in the title, although as you can see, windows.h is included. How could I fix that? Or is there a different header that is needed in order to use these?

Comment: Next time please try to search for similar questions. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596219/input-was-not-declared-in-this-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx) is only supported since Windows >= 2000.

Therefore, you need to [define `WINVER` and/or `_WIN32_WINNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt) to be able to use it. Read [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.